# Error while compiling with cmake: cannot find -ldwmapi

Tags: c, cmake

**Edit:** Im using MinGW-x86_64 on windows

When Im trying to compile a gtk+ 3 c project with cmake, I have this error message on the log:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.1.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Jonas\ClionProjects\tutorial\cmake-build-debug --target tutorial -- -j 4
[ 50%] Linking C executable tutorial.exe
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ldwmapi
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles\tutorial.dir\build.make:96: recipe for target 'tutorial.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [tutorial.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/tutorial.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/tutorial.dir/all' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/tutorial.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/tutorial.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [tutorial] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'tutorial' failed
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt, in there I added gtk3 and its libraries, but when Im trying to compile, it has the errors mentioned before.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(tutorial)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)

set(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/pkg-config.exe")

FIND_PACKAGE(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable(tutorial ${SOURCE_FILES})

ADD_DEFINITIONS(${GTK3_CFLAGS_OTHER})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(tutorial ${GTK3_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: I won't post an answer as I haven't used windows in years, but it looks like dwmapi.dll is a windows system binary. My guess is that you should make sure that file is in your build path.

Comment: What output with `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` ?

Comment: C:\msys64\mingw64\bin>pkg-config.exe --libs gtk+-3.0
-LC:/msys64/mingw64/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lwinmm -ldwmapi -lsetupapi -lcfgmgr32 -lz -lpangowin32-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl

Answer (score 0):

dwmapi.dll is provided only for Vista. So I guess that it is a bug of package of gtk+-3.0. And `-ldwmapi` is not required for your OS. Below is a workaround to fix this issue. I don't make sure this will solve your issue. Note that this is self-responsibility.

1. make backup-copy of gdk-3.0.pc, gdk-broadway-3.0.pc, gdk-win32-3.0.pc in `C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\pkgconfig`
2. open those files in vim, remove `-ldwmapi` and `:wq`

## UPDATE

Let's create libdwmapi.a

1. download def file from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/master/mingw-w64-crt/libarm32/dwmapi.def)
2. `dlltool -d dwmapi.def -l libdwmapi.a`

Comment: dwmapi.dll is in C:/windows/system32 located in windows 10

Comment: it creates the libdwmapi.a as 0 byte file

Comment: C:\MinGW\bin>dlltool -d dwmapi.def -l libdwmapi.a                          
dlltool: CreateProcess

Comment: ok, I created a new mingw directory and installed all packages I need and it worked